# ROS2 Communication between 32 bit and 64 bit systems

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ros2 foxy and my setup consists on `32 bit debian-10 docker` running `demo_node_cpp talker` node and `64 bit Ubuntu 20.04 docker` (osrf/ros:foxy-desktop) running `demo_node_cpp listener` node. Both the docker running with `--net=host` flag, so they can see each other through network.

I can't see any communication between each other as there is no logging on the terminal on listener side. Also there are no results  to `ros2 node list` . But when both docker are 64 bit they are communicating with each other.

Is my observation is correct ? or Is there something wrong ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389410/ros2-communication-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-systems/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like i made a made a mistake by adding a `--net=host` flag while running the docker.  After following this [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html) things looks fine.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2021-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0